# Can I get a Keras model from a .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, protocol-buffers

I have a ptocolbuffer file for a VGG model.I need to generate the keras model. Can I use the .pb file to generate Keras model so that I can use the Keras features like summary?

I loaded the .pb file in tf and generate model cofigs and layer weights.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util


GRAPH_PB_PATH = './small_vgg_tf_graph.pb'
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print("load graph")
   with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   sess.graph.as_default()
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
   graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
   names = []
   for t in graph_nodes:
      names.append(t.name)
   with open('names.txt','w') as fh:
        for i in names:
         fh.write(str(i)+'\n')

   weight_nodes = [n for n in graph_def.node if n.op == 'Const']
   with open('weights.txt','w') as fh:
      for n in weight_nodes:
               fh.write("Name of the node - %s" % n.name+'\n')
               fh.write("Value - " )
               fh.write(str(tensor_util.MakeNdarray(n.attr['value'].tensor))+'\n')


   with open('ops.txt','w') as fh:               
      for op in sess.graph.get_operations():
         fh.write(str(op)+'\n')
```

I want to generate Keras like summary file

Comment: Hi, sorry it's been a long time, but I'm wondering that do you have a solution now? (Cause' I have the same problem Q_Q)

Comment: I had identified the graph nodes, operation types, their input and outputs, and automate model generation with Keras modules.